# select data from global temporary tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, global, temporary

I had created a global temporary tables with ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROW CLAUSE.
But when I run the application and tried to view & validate the data in GTT table, there is no data available.

Is it any option to view the data in GTT even after I close the application and my process done.

How can I achieve this??

Comment: The whole point of a global temporary table is to store data at the session or transaction level - it is not going to be retained when you disconnect. You’d need a regular table for that.

Comment: As the linked duplicate states, a GTT will not keep the data beyond your current session; that's why it is a **TEMPORARY** table. If you want to keep your data between sessions then use a normal (non-temporary) table.